# Is it possible to auto-insert corresponding labels to chapter, sections, subsections,..?

Tags: texstudio

I want to auto-insert a label when I complete a new chapter, section, subsection, ... and so using the auto-complete function. Essentially I want to overwrite the existing one to do the following:

Suppose I type `\chapter{myChapter}`, I want a `\label{cha:myChapter}`.

For a section it would be `\section{mySection}` and `\label{sec:mySection}`.

For subsection this, `\subsection{mySubsection}` and `\label{subsec:mySubsection}`.

So, is there a way to modify the TeXStudio auto-complete to do that or a macro, or..?

PS.: Yes, I know that is ultra lazy of me. :)

Comment: Not related to the technical challenge, but real section titles tend to be poor choices for labels. They're almost always too long and may contain all sorts of markup (spaces, math mode, ...).

Comment: oh good to know. for my paper I dont need that, in fact I did not even know that you could do something like this.

Comment: AUCTeX/RefTeX under emacs can be customized to offer default labels of this form, e.g. via a customization of the form `'(reftex-insert-label-flags (quote ("s" t)))`

Answer (score 3):

There's a context menu entry "Create Label" for structure elements in the structure panel. This creates `\label{sec:a-section-title}` for `\section{A Section Title}`. The Format is not configurable. It's always `sec:` (also for chapter) followed by a lowercase hyphenated version of the title.

If you need more control, you can create a script for the task. See the [TeXstudio manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#SECTION33) for details on scripting and the [wiki page for example scripts](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/wiki/Scripts/).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following script I wrote for myself and change it according to your need

```
%SCRIPT
function myfunc(){
linenumber = cursor.lineNumber();
txt = editor.text(linenumber);
ind = txt.search("\{");
ind2 = txt.search("\}")
key = txt.substring(ind+1,ind2)
return "\\section\{"+key+"\}\label\{sec:"+key+"\}";
}

cur = editor.document().cursor(1,0,2000)
for(i = 1;i<100;i++){
editor.replace("\\section\{\w+\}$","",cur,myfunc)
}
```